# only show pivotchart not pivot table

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010

I see that I can only create a pivotchart from a pivottable, but since the filtering options are on the chart, and the table is not important:
**Is there a way to hide a pivottable If I only want to show the pivot chart?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A PivotChart and its associated PivotTable report must always be in the same workbook (as the Chart's data is based on the the table). However you can place the Chart on one worksheet and have the table on a separate one, effectively hiding the table from view.

Answer (score 2):

In Excel2013 when creating a PivotChart there is a checkbox at the bottom saying "Add this data to the Data Model" which hides the table (if checked).

Answer (score 0):

You can also place the pivot table in a separate sheet, then right click the sheet name and select Hide. This way no one can access the Pivot Table without unhiding the sheet first.